# Java: Cannot find symbol error on Map, HashMap

Tags: java, missing-symbols

I'm trying to run this code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class ScanReg {
  public Map<Integer, ArrayList<Long>> scanMap = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Long>>();
}
```

within this class:

```
import java.util.*;

public class NxtStart {
  ScanReg sr = new ScanReg();
}
```

This keeps giving me the following error:

```
.\ScanReg.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
        public Map<Integer, ArrayList<Long>> scanMap = new HashMap<Integer, Arra
yList<Long>>();
               ^
  symbol:   class Map
  location: class ScanReg
.\ScanReg.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
        public Map<Integer, ArrayList<Long>> scanMap = new HashMap<Integer, Arra
yList<Long>>();
                                                           ^
  symbol:   class HashMap
  location: class ScanReg
2 errors
```

Can somebody please tell me why?

Comment: You don't have your own local package named `java.util` do you? I would try to import the whole class name: `import java.util.Map;` and same for the other util classes used such as HashMap.

Comment: Kal may be on to something (1+ to him!).

Comment: I cannot recreate this based on the info in the question.  Something else is going on.  And since the OP most likely doesn't care anymore, it should be closed as "not reproducible".

Answer (score 2):

You're possibly compiling using Java 1.4 and using generics ( only available from 1.5 onwards ).

Comment: Sorry .. I cannot reproduce the problem. I copied your ScanReg.java and it compiled fine.

Answer (score -2):

You need to declare your inner class as **static**

```
public static class ScanReg {}
```

Else, put in different java file and import ScanReg.

Comment: This won't solve the problem he was trying to solve.  It was about library classes and imports.  Also, note that this is an **ancient** question.  If the OP hasn't solved the problem by now, he will no longer care.

Comment: I recreated the problem and test this to be working solution

Comment: Well I >could not< recreate the problem.  When I compile those two files from the command line (Java 8).  I don't get any compilation errors.  There was something "funky" that the OP was not telling us.